# Looking out of bounds in a 2D Lua table

Tags: arrays, lua, lua-table

I sometimes make small games in Lua, and often have to implement a 2D array as a grid or a board. When I want to check the cells surrounding a particular cell I usually give the 2D array a metatable so that when grid[outOfBoundsNum] is indexed it returns an empty table instead of an error:

```
setmetatable(grid, {
    __index = 
    function(t, key)
        if not table[key] then
            return {}
        else
            return table[key]
        end
    end})
```

So when `grid[outOfBoundsNum][anything]` is called, it returns `nil`. Then, to check surrounding cells I do something like this :

```
for k, v in ipairs(neighbours) do
    local cell = grid[v[1][v[2]]
    if cell then -- check if this is actually within the 2D array
        if cell == 1 then 
            -- do something
        elseif cell == 2 then
            -- do something else
        ...
    end
end
```

This works, but it seems awkward to me. Is there a nicer or better way of doing it?

Comment: Why does `neighbours` contain `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}` and not `{cell1, cell2, ...}`?

Comment: No reason, it's just an example. The module I wrote actually uses the second method {cell1, cell2, ...}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the metatable.

```
for k, v in ipairs(neighbours) do
   local cell = grid[v[1]] and grid[v[1]][v[2]]

   if cell == 1 then 
      -- do something
   elseif cell == 2 then
      -- do something else
   ... 
   end 
end
```

Should do the job. It is a relatively common lua idiom to use logical `and` and `or` in expressions to act like the ternary operator in C. 
So this line is equivalent to:

```
local cell = nil
if grid[v[1]]~=nil then
    cell = grid[v[1]][v[2]]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a `forEachNeighbor()` function which would take the grid, a position and a function and then call it with each existing neighborfield, i.e. encapsule the loop and the outer `if` in your second snippet in a function, you would use like:

```
forEachNeighbor(grid, position, function(cell)
    if cell == 1 then
        -- do something
    elseif cell == 2 then
        -- do something else
    ...
end)
```

Also, you could provide an `at()` function which would take a grid position as one parameter and return the corresponding field or `nil`, so that `grid[v[1]][v[2]]` becomes `at(grid, v)`. This could also be implemented in addition to or instead of the `__index` metamethod.

For the `__index` metamethod itself: First, you probably meant `t` instead of `table` and  `rawget(t, key)` instead of `t[key]` (which would cause infinite recursion).
But as lhf pointed out, the check is altogether unnecessary, because `__index` is [only called when the key is not present in `t`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4). So you could just write:

```
__index = function(t, key)
    return {}
end
```

One last remark:

> I sometimes make small games in Lua, and often have to implement a 2D array

Why don't you implement it once and reuse it in other games? That's what [modules](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.3) are for!

Comment: There is no need for calling `rawget` in `__index` because `__index` is called only when the key is not in the table.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't just make a module already ... thanks for the suggestion!